# How to create complex class from JSON

Tags: c#, class, json.net

I have below complex JSON format and I want to create C# class from that 
Can any one help to sort it out the class and hierarchy of the classes.

```
{
'scriptVersion': 1,
  'pagesData': [
    {
      'state': 'ABC',
      'idNo': '55',
      'noOfRecords': {
        '10': {
          'key': 'key1',
          'value': 'value1'
        },
        '201': {
          'key': 'key2',
          'value': 'value2'
        },
        '300': {
          'key': 'key3',
          'value': 'value3'
        }
        }
    }]
}
```

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: I try to create class and sub class for the nested part but confusion and query is related to 'noOfRecords' section that how maintain that as values are changing for 10,201,300

Answer (score 1):

Copy the json string

Paste in VS via [ Edit | Paste Special | Paste Json as Classes ]

The are also multiple online json to C# generator tools

Comment: Yes, That I know to create JSON class but if you noticed under "noOfRecords" value of "10","201" will be dynamic so confusion is how to create property for that

Comment: Well it is kinda a weird json i expected to have a integer on a property 'noOfRecords'. This json is implying the noOfRecords property has 3 complex properties named .10,201,300.

Should these be in a array of some sort. Ask the guys who gave you this json if the have a documentation for it, i've got a gut feeling telling me this json isn't finished.

Comment: Ok, So we can have n no of that types of records under noOfRecords so will not able to create common class for that?

Answer (score 0):

base on your json code this is the class

```
public class c10
{
    public string key { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}

public class c201
{
    public string key { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}

public class c300
{
    public string key { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}

public class NoOfRecords
{
    public c10 { get; set; }
    public c201 { get; set; }
    public c300 { get; set; }
}

public class PagesData
{
    public string state { get; set; }
    public string idNo { get; set; }
    public NoOfRecords noOfRecords { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public int scriptVersion { get; set; }
    public List<PagesData> pagesData { get; set; }
}
```